# Как собрать maven проэкт в Intellij IDEA с использованием java, selenium, testng?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, selenium, testng

Нужно собрать проект с тестами и использовать их для регрессионного тестирования, но не знаю как это правильно сделать. Точнее какие бы варианты я не пробовала положительных результатов всё нет. Помогите пожалуйста.
Проект имеет структуру:
[image: Структура]

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>1</groupId>
    <artifactId>11</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
       <build>
        <!--<sourceDirectory>D:\Автотесты\page factory\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
        <scriptSourceDirectory>D:\Автотесты\page factory\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>D:\Автотесты\page factory\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>D:\Автотесты\page factory\target\classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>D:\Автотесты\page factory\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>D:\Автотесты\page factory\src\main\resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>D:\Автотесты\page factory\src\test\resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>-->

        <directory>D:\Автотесты\page factory\target</directory>
        <finalName>11-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
       <!---->  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
         <resources>
             <resource>
                 <directory>src</directory>
                 <excludes>
                     <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                 </excludes>
             </resource>
         </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <!--<fork>true</fork>
                    <executable> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe</executable>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                      <!--  <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile> -->
                        <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Registraciy</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Registraciy
```

Comment: Какие ошибки показывает и как запускаете проект?
Попробуйте в корне проекта выполнить команду:
mvn clean test -X
и посмотреть, что выведет в лог.